# Cloudinary node.js progress of uploading

Tags: node.js, electron, cloudinary

I used cloudinary in angularjs web SPA and there was nice callback named `.progress`:

```
.progress(function (info) {
    //file.progress = Math.round((e.loaded * 100.0) / info.total);
    //file.status = "Uploading... " + file.progress + "%"
    console.log(info);
})
```

which was basically logging object with data about uploading status info.

Now I'm wondering if I'm able to somehow get same progress when uploading by nodeJS code on server side

```
cloudinary.v2.uploader.upload(path, { resource_type: "video" }, function(err, success) {
    console.log('err: ' + JSON.stringify(err));
    console.log('suc: ' + JSON.stringify(success.secure_url));
});
```

I'm using electron so I can communicate nodeJS side with front with ipcMain I can send custom event from node to front so I can just pass new event every 1% of uploading and display some progressbar on front.

But since cloduinary docs doesn't provide some additional info of how to get status of uploading with nodejs I don't know how to do that and if it is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After much more googling I found [information on github](https://github.com/cloudinary/cloudinary_npm/issues/84) from cloudinary collaborator that progress isn't available for server-side uploading.