# Upload movie to cloudinary from angularJS SPA inside electron

Tags: angularjs, node.js, electron, cloudinary

I want to upload file from user disc to cloudinary from front side of electron app which is angularJS SPA.

I already did uploading photo from angularJS by selecting photo from `input[file]` but this time I want to upload movie by absolute path to file on user disc.

Since I use electron I'm able to use nodeJS packages as `path` inside front layer so that's what I'll use for defining path to `.webm` file as it lays in root directory of application.

```
$scope.uploadVideo = function () {

    var filePath = __dirname + '\\videos\\example.webm';
    console.log(filePath);

    $upload.upload({
        url: "https://api.cloudinary.com/v1_1/" + cloudinary.config().cloud_name + "/upload",
        data: {
            upload_preset: cloudinary.config().upload_preset,
            file: filePath
        }
    })
    .progress(function (info) {
        console.log(info);
    })
    .then(function (res) {
        console.log(res);
    });
};
```

`filePath` is:

> C:\Users\Admin\Documents\ngb\desktopApp\videos\example.webm

which is correct path to file. However above code doesn't work and give this error:

> Possibly unhandled rejection: {"data":{"error":{"message":"Unsupported source URL: C:\Users\Admin\Documents\ngb\desktopApp\videos\example.webm"}},"status":400,"config":{"method":"POST","transformRequest":[null],"transformResponse":

I think I'm not able to to send from front to cloudinary movie by absolute path to file but I hope I'm wrong. Also I could do same with nodeJS side of electron (actually I tried and it's working) but in nodeJS I don't have this `.progress` callback which show current info about uploading progress which helps creating some progressbar on front to show how long left.

Question is if it's possible to send it to cloudinary by angularJS using path to file and if not how to get progress of uploading by nodeJS. **Edit** I've created [separate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51573300/cloudinary-node-js-progress-of-uploading) for second question. **Edit2** After much more googling I found [information on github](https://github.com/cloudinary/cloudinary_npm/issues/84) from cloudinary collaborator that progress isn't available for server-side uploading so I reply to my own question in above link.

---

**Edit**
As the error is saying that they doesn't support path like this I discard idea of giving path to file in API call. Instead I want to encode my video file into base64 format and then pass it to cloudinary as they say [here](https://support.cloudinary.com/hc/en-us/articles/203125741-Can-I-upload-using-DATA-URI-BASE64-) that it's possible:

```
$scope.uploadVideo = function () {

    var filePath = __dirname + '\\videos\\example.webm';
    var buff = Buffer.from(filePath).toString('base64');
    console.log(filePath);
    console.log(buff);

    $upload.upload({
        url: "https://api.cloudinary.com/v1_1/" + cloudinary.config().cloud_name + "/upload",
        data: {
            upload_preset: cloudinary.config().upload_preset,
            file: 'base64,' + buff
        }
    })
    .progress(function (info) {
        console.log(info);
    })
    .then(function (res) {
        console.log(res);
    });
};
```

But it still doesn't work.. It console log

> C:\Users\Admin\Documents\ngb\desktopApp\videos\example.webm
>
> QzpcVXNlcnNcQm9yeXNcRG9jdW1lbnRzXGlndFxkZXNrdG9wQXBwXHZpZGVvc1xleGFtcGxlLndlYm0=

and error is still same:

> Possibly unhandled rejection: {"data":{"error":{"message":"Unsupported source URL: base64,QzpcVXNlcnNcQm9yeXNcRG9jdW1lbnRzXGlndFxkZXNrdG9wQXBwXHZpZGVvc1xleGFtcGxlLndlYm0="}},"status":400,"config":{"method":"POST","

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The URI needs to include the actual file contents and not just the path. For example, using formdata-

```
(function() {
    var f = document.getElementById('f');

    if (f.files.length)
        processFile();

    f.addEventListener('change', processFile, false);

    function processFile(e) {

        var f = document.getElementById('f');
        var file = f.files[0];

        console.log(file);
        var formdata = new FormData();

        formdata.append('file', file);
        //formdata.append('cloud_name', '<cloud_name>');
        formdata.append('upload_preset', '<upload_preset>');

        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('POST', "https://api.cloudinary.com/v1_1/<cloud_name>/upload",true);

        xhr.onload = function () {
            // do something to response
            console.log(this.responseText);
        };

        xhr.send(formdata);
    }
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

@rcstraus correctly point out that I'm not converting to base64 file but just string which was path to file.

Except that my `file: data` was incorrect I should have `file: 'data:video/webm;base64,' + buff` where buff is file in base64 not path.

And the working code is:

```
$scope.uploadVideo = function () {
    $scope.selected.state = $scope.state[3];

    fs.readFile('./videos/example.webm', (err, data) => {
        if(err) alert(err);
        var buff = Buffer.from(data).toString('base64');
        $upload.upload({
            url: "https://api.cloudinary.com/v1_1/" + cloudinary.config().cloud_name + "/upload",
            data: {
                upload_preset: cloudinary.config().upload_preset,
                //tags: 'myphotoalbum',
                //context: 'photo=' + $scope.title,
                file: 'data:video/webm;base64,' + buff
            }
        })
        .progress(function (info) {
            //file.progress = Math.round((e.loaded * 100.0) / info.total);
            //file.status = "Uploading... " + file.progress + "%"
            console.log(info);
        })
        .then(function (res) {
            console.log(res);
        });
    });

};
```

it's combaining of node and angularJS and ng-file-upload package, electron make it works.